# Iterating MongoDB cursor blocks forever

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I'm using the MongoDB C# driver 1.8.1.20 with Mongo 2.4.3. I use the following infinite loop to poll new messages from a capped collection and process them as they come (with a tailable cursor and await data). It works for the most part, but in production, it seems that from time to time the call to enumerator.MoveNext() blocks and never returns. This causes the loop to stall, and my application no longer receives updates. It seems to be happening when the connection is closed unexpectedly.

```
while (true)
{
    try
    {
        using (MongoCursorEnumerator<QueueMessage> enumerator = GetCursor())
        {
            while (!enumerator.IsDead)
            {
                while (enumerator.MoveNext()) // This is blocking forever when connection is temporarily lost
                    this.processMessage(enumerator.Current);
            }
        }
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
         Trace.TraceError("Error in the ReceiveCore loop:  " + ex.ToString());
     }
}
```

The GetCursor function does this:

```
cursor = (MongoCursorEnumerator<QueueMessage>)collection
    .FindAllAs<QueueMessage>()
    .SetFlags(QueryFlags.AwaitData | QueryFlags.TailableCursor | QueryFlags.NoCursorTimeout)
    .SetSortOrder(SortBy.Ascending("$natural"))
    .GetEnumerator();
```

Why is that blocking forever, and what can I do to make sure it throws an exception when it can't complete (possibly by timing out)?

Answer (score 0):

I think I would just remove the QueryFlags.NoCursorTimeout, then let it timeout occasionally and just restart.